# Cannot use name when deploying application in Mulesoft Cloudhub

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I am using Mule 4 and I am looking to deploy a new application in Cloudhub but it is not allowing me to use the name "customer-api".  There is no other application called that in any of the environments and I cannot see it used in API manager either.  There was an API called customer-api which has been deleted so not sure if this name could still be cached/ registered somewhere and the entry needs to be cleared.

The only place I can see that name used is in the Anypoint Exchange but wouldn't think that would impact what we are deploying.

Does anybody know what could be preventing me from using that name?

[image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Every MuleSoft customer uses the cloudhub, which means it has to be "globally" unique. Try `customer-api-randomString` and it should work.